# C# using Enumerable range as int

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I need to get a number of value from a xml file into a chart.  I'm trying to use enumerable range to that.

```
IEnumerable<Int32> seq = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).ToArray();
chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(package[seq].value1);
```

But its saying that it cannot convert  to ínt'. When I try

```
var seq = Convert.ToInt32(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).ToArray());
```

I get that it unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' .

What to do?

Comment: What is the Method signature for `chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY()`, and why type of collection is `package`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY` seems to only take an `int`, not an `int[]`. You'll need to iterate over the range and add the points separately.